# How to resolve "enter the password for credential storage" issue?

Tags: wi-fi, certificates, https

So I am playing around with fiddler web proxy. I need to decrypt https traffic. So I am trying to put the fiddler root CA cert in my device trust store. But it keeps asking me `"Enter the password for credential storage"`. If i enter anything and click enter I see an `Toast` message saying

> Credential storage has been erased

and the password prompt comes again. This goes on in a loop. For the record I have selected `"Wifi"` as the Credential use instead of `"App n VPN"` (not sure of that matters).

[image]

Next wired thing that I noticed is that after each prompt the description changes for label

> The package contains

The value for it increases each time the password prompt is shown. For eg - 3 CA certificates, 4 CA certificates and so on...

[image]

As much as I want my device to accept this certificate I would appreciate if someone could explain the "credential storage" concept and the weird increment of CA certs text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could now install the certificate. I had to disable pattern screen lock and try installing certificate again. This time it asked me to setup security - pin or password.

[image]

That I did and cert got installed. Got the solution from android central forum.

http://forums.androidcentral.com/google-nexus-7-tablet-2012/301151-credential-storage.html

I guess that thread is for VPN but same solution works for Wifi certs as well. Please do add if anyone has any additional info on this or workaround.

Comment: Can you post the relevant solution from that link you mentioned? If in future the link goes down then at least the reader will have your answer with the relevant solution to work with.

Comment: I did at the very start. Disable security lock and install cert again (or vpn).

Comment: I guess I didn't notice it. My bad, but I submitted an edit to highlight the solution you mentioned. It shall be reflected here if accepted after being peer reviewed.